# Combine multiple maps in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

This is a reproductible example of an issue I am facing. I am trying to create maps with ggplot2 in multiple stages. Here is the issue I face. 
Consider the data `border`with the polygons of states in US at the Mexican border, and `border.county`with the polygons of the counties in these states. The following code allows you to get the data:

```
library(maps)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

USA <- get_googlemap(center = 'usa', zoom = 4,  
                     style = 'administrative|element:labels|visibility:off')

us.df <- map_data("state") 
border <- subset(us.df, 
                 region %in% c("california","arizona","new mexico","texas"))

counties <- map_data("county")
border.county <- subset(counties,
                        region %in% c("california","arizona","new mexico","texas"))
```

Now I wan to create a map, with the background of a map from Google Maps, with the state polygons and the county borders. If I do the following, it works neatly:

```
Allmap <- ggmap(USA) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = region, group = group), 
               data=border,  color = "white") +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat,  group = group), 
               data=border.county, fill=NA, color="red")
```

Now if I wanted to create this map in multiple stages, I hit problems. I just want the county boundaries for  background information (as sort of 'recurrent theme'), and I will create multiple maps with changing information at the state level. So I create the 'background map' with counties, which works fine:

```
Countmap <- ggmap(USA) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat,  group = group), 
               data=border.county, fill=NA, color="red")
```

And now I try to combine it with the state maps:

```
Statmap <- ggmap(USA) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = region, group = group), 
               data=border,  color = "white") + 
  Countmap
```

That gives me the error:

```
 Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot
```

How can I solve this? I can combine the maps in the other way (as in: `Statmap <- Countmap + geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = region, group = group), data=border,  color = "white")`); however, that puts the counties under the state boundaries.

I also know this specific problem has the easy solution of just drawing a map with the states first, and combine it with the counties in a second stage. However, in my real scenario, that is not an option because the recurrent theme of the map is something that needs to be drawn in second place : cities and geographic borders (like my county boundaries here).

This is the map I want to create:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, you don't want to combine *maps*. You want to combine *layers*, specifically, to overlay the county outlines on changing state-level maps.

Try this:

```
# define county outlines as a geom_polygon layer
county.layer <- geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
                             data = border.county, fill = NA, color = "red")

# add county.layer as the last layer to your state-level map
Statmap <- ggmap(USA) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = region, group = group), 
               data=border,  color = "white") +
  county.layer

Statmap
```

[image: single-layer plot]

**Edit in response to comment**

If you have multiple county layers to plot, place them in a list:

```
border.county2 <- subset(counties, region %in% c("montana")) 

layer2 <- list(geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
                            data = border.county2, fill = NA, color = "blue"),
               geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
                            data = border.county, fill = NA, color = "red"))

Statmap <- ggmap(USA) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = region, group = group), 
               data=border,  color = "white") +
  layer2
```

[image: multi-layer plot]

Comment: Thank you; this works fine in this example. However, I have an issue because in the real case, my first layer has multiple 'sub-layers'; which yields the error `non-numeric argument to binary operator`. 
Here is the example: 
`border.county2 <- subset(counties,region %in% c("montana"))
layer2<-geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),  data = border.county2, fill = NA, color = "blue") +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = border.county, fill = NA, color = "red")`

Comment: @Doon_Bogan Thanks for clarifying. See if my edited answer works for you?

Comment: Yes! Thank you.